# Same image texture for merged shape

Tags: three.js, aframe

I have made a closed hemisphere by merging geometries of a hemisphere and a circle. I have a 360degree image for texture. I want the image to be applied as the texture to the combined geometry. Currently it is applying the texture twice: to the hemisphere and the circle separately.

I have seen some answers on editing the UV mapping, but I am not sure how to go about it.

Here is the code.

```
      var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
      loader.setPath(srcPath);
      loader.load("./texture.jpg", function(texture) {

        var hemiSphereGeom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, radialSegments, Math.round(radialSegments / 4), 0, Math.PI * 2, 0, Math.PI * 0.5);
        var objMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
            map: texture,
            shading: THREE.FlatShading
          });
          objMaterial.side = THREE.BackSide;
        var capGeom = new THREE.CircleGeometry(radius, radialSegments);
        capGeom.rotateX(Math.PI * 0.5);
        var singleGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();

        var cap = new THREE.Mesh(capGeom);
        var hemiSphere = new THREE.Mesh(hemiSphereGeom);

        hemiSphere.updateMatrix();
        singleGeometry.merge(hemiSphere.geometry, hemiSphere.matrix);

        cap.updateMatrix();
        singleGeometry.merge(cap.geometry, cap.matrix);

        el.setObject3D('hemisphere',new THREE.Mesh(singleGeometry  , objMaterial));
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the code is seeing the closed hemisphere as the two separate entities still. I would try a 3D modeling program and make the shape there and loading it into the AFrame code. Then load the texture on the back side of the geometry.